# CScript.exe - Corrupt file

Tags: windows-server-2003, chkdsk

I'm getting the following error on a Windows Server 2003 machine:

> "CScript.exe - Corrupt file.  The file or directory
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll is corrupt and unreadable.  Please run
>   the Chkdsk utility."

I have a few questions:

1. Will running Chkdsk cause problems, such as making the computer unbootable into the Operating System?
2. Which should I download a copy of "shell32.dll" from Microsoft or some other computer and copy it to the server as a backup?
3. What safety measures should I take when running 'Chkdsk' on a Windows Server 2003 machine?

Comment: Do you have a backup system in place?  Can you simply restore the file?  If you don't have a backup system in place, then the answer to #3 is setup a backup system ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes if it also detects hard disk errors. Or errors in other files that a responsible for a boot.
2. I'm not aware that you can download a single file from Microsoft. So copy it from a machine with exact Service Pack and Patch level. But if your hard disk is broken that wouldn't help anyway.
3. You have to have a (full) backup! If your repair fails, then you can do a disaster recovery.

Answer (score 0):

1 - No, chkdsk shouldn't cause any problems unless the drive is dying, in which case you could get more corrupt files as sectors continue to go bad as it's checking the drive.

2 - I wouldn't recommend it unless you know for absolute certain that the other copy of w2k3 is patched exactly the same. The best way to recover it is to boot into repair mode off the install dvd. Likely your HD is going out though (See #1), so best make plans to replace it now.

3 - You'd want to boot into recovery mode/safe mode and run with /X if possible (Forces volume to be dismounted so no writes can occur while running chkdsk). Maybe someone else with more experience with chkdsk and NTFS can chime in on this one, though.

But I'm really thinking that you probably have other corrupt files you don't know about, and you really should be trying to immediately replace the drive. Hopefully you're running on raid-1 (Mirrored) or some other raid level to help mitigate drive/data loss.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same answer as mine?!